# Error while trying to authenticate login using firebase in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am creating a logging system using firebase, i have connected my project to firebase and enabled 
   email and password authentication and added users. But when i run the app and try to login using the 
   email and password that i have added,it shows the below error and the app crashes.

```
class _AdminLoginState extends State<AdminLogin> {
  String _username, _password;
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formkey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  Future<void> login() async{
    final  formState = _formkey.currentState;
    if(formState.validate()){
      formState.save();
      try{

        final FirebaseUser user = (await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: _username, password: _password)).user;
        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Dashboard()));
      }catch(e){
        print(e.message);
      }
     }
  }
}
```

when i enter the username and password the app shutdowns and throws me this error.

```
W/BiChannelGoogleApi(29343): [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzak@4b54d30
E/JavaBinder(29343): *** Uncaught remote exception!  (Exceptions are not yet supported across processes.)
E/JavaBinder(29343): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/util/ArrayMap;
E/JavaBinder(29343):    at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzam.zzc(Unknown Source:22)
E/JavaBinder(29343):    at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzam.zzde(Unknown Source:17)
E/JavaBinder(29343):    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzep.zza(Unknown Source:9)
E/JavaBinder(29343):    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:735)
E/JavaBinder(29343): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.util.ArrayMap" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/m20zero.adminbookingpage-tivSbYSPqm94eArdHgurKQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/m20zero.adminbookingpage-tivSbYSPqm94eArdHgurKQ==/lib/arm64, /data/app/m20zero.adminbookingpage-tivSbYSPqm94eArdHgurKQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
E/JavaBinder(29343):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
E/JavaBinder(29343):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
E/JavaBinder(29343):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
E/JavaBinder(29343):    ... 16 more
E/AndroidRuntime(29343): FATAL EXCEPTION: Binder:29343_1
E/AndroidRuntime(29343): Process: m20zero.adminbookingpage, PID: 29343
E/AndroidRuntime(29343): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/util/ArrayMap;
E/AndroidRuntime(29343):    at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzam.zzc(Unknown Source:22)
E/AndroidRuntime(29343):    at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzam.zzde(Unknown Source:17)
E/AndroidRuntime(29343):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_auth.zza.onTransact(Unknown Source:13)
E/AndroidRuntime(29343):    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:735)
E/AndroidRuntime(29343): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.util.ArrayMap" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/m20zero.adminbookingpage-tivSbYSPqm94eArdHgurKQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/m20zero.adminbookingpage-tivSbYSPqm94eArdHgurKQ==/lib/arm64, /data/app/m20zero.adminbookingpage-tivSbYSPqm94eArdHgurKQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
E/AndroidRuntime(29343):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
E/AndroidRuntime(29343):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
E/AndroidRuntime(29343):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
E/AndroidRuntime(29343):    ... 16 more
I/Process (29343): Sending signal. PID: 29343 SIG: 9
Lost connection to device.
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the minSdk version on build.gradle file?